# How to set a value in textarea Yii2 activeform from a variable?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following code, how to set a value from a variable in the textarea? Thanks.

```
<?php

$connection = \Yii::$app->db;

$sql = 'SELECT user_profile_name FROM users_profiles WHERE user_id = :_id';
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindParam(':_id',$userId);
$username = $command->queryScalar();
$command->execute();
?>

<?=  $form->field($model, 'name')
        ->textInput(['editable' => true,'value' => $username]) ?>
```

Comment: Actually the latter worked when I logged back into my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is you need set value when create new record. 
Please set with:

```
if($model->isNewRecord){
$model->name= 'Value';
```

}

Because, when update, will show name. So not need set from form field.

and show as textarea field:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textarea() ?>
```